# How do I clear the values in a PHP array while maintaining its keys?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to take an array and clear all of its values while maintaining its keys.  By "clear" I mean replace with an empty type value, such as '' or null.  PHP obviously has quite a few [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), but I didn't find anything there that does exactly this.  I am currently doing it this way:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) $value = ''
```

My question is, is there some built-in php function I overlooked, or any other way I can accomplish this without iterating over the array at this level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what your memory/performance/object-management needs are, it's hard to say what's best. Here are some "I just want something short" alternatives:

```
$array = array_fill_keys(array_keys($a),""); // Simple, right?

$array = array_map(function(){return "";},$a); // More flexible but easier to typo
```

If you have an array that's being passed around by reference and really want to wipe it, direct iteration is probably your best bet.

```
foreach($a as $k => $v){
    $a[$k] = "";
}
```

Iteration with references:

```
/* This variation is a little more dangerous, because $v will linger around
 * and can cause bizarre bugs if you reuse the same variable name later on,
 * so make sure you unset() it when you're done.
 */ 
foreach($a as $k => &$v){
    $v = "";
}
unset($v);
```

If you have a performance need, I suggest you benchmark these yourself with appropriately-sized arrays and PHP versions.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is array_map

```
$array = array_map(function($x) { return '';}, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_keys` to get the keys. You can then use `array_flip` if you like, although this will assign the values 0 through length-1 to the keys.

There is no single built-in function for this. You might try:

```
array_combine(array_keys($array),array_fill(0,count($array)-1,""));
```

But really the code you have right now does the job just fine.

Comment: You do know about [`array_fill_keys`](http://php.net/array_fill_keys), right?  `array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), '');`